# From time to time, the system does not find a file that exists

Tags: 7, files

From time to time (1 in 20 pages or so), I receive the following Drupal error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/sites/all/themes/MYTEMPLATE/lightGallery/dist/js/lightgallery.js):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in _locale_parse_js_file()
 (line 1488 of /home/[MACHINE_NAME]/domains/[DOMAIN_URL]/public_html/includes/locale.inc).
```

The folder has permissions, it works perfectly, but the error message is persistent. I don't know why it happens and how to avoid it.

Comment: If the file exists, it's a permissions issue. I know you said it's not, but that's the only thing it can be if the file is actually there. Maybe it's a file permissions problem on the parent folder, maybe on the file itself. Maybe the owner/group of the file is not correct for whichever user is executing Drupal (eg. apache).

Comment: It happens consistently, when I delete the cache and visit another page. Only in that case. It is always the same file, that gets the owner and permissions exactly like the others in that folder and much of the entire site. It seems a bug.

Comment: That file is in your theme. Is it maybe a file that is being created by your theme somehow? And does the file exist after the cache is cleared?

Comment: Yes, the file is in my theme. I have solved the problem, it was for not using the $base_url , i. e., the absolute path. Thanks for your comments, they help me to trace back the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was traced back to a call to `drupal_add_js` with relative URLs. I have added a prefix of **drupal_get_path** and the problem has disappeared for ever; it seems sometimes Drupal did not find the file because it thought it was in another location, but later it found it. This is why clearing the cache reproduced the problem. With the absolute path, problem is vanished.

Comment: You should use `drupal_get_path` rather then `$base_url` for this purpose.